# firebase_ui_oauth_google Import and GoogleProvider is not working

Tags: flutter, google-signin, firebaseui

Couldn't resolve the package 'firebase_ui_oauth_google' in 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart'.

https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps?hl=en#6

I'm following this guide, but at this part both of code are red lined

```
import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart';

GoogleProvider(clientId: "484519518330-mtnhjeoiqjf07tnhe5bjqac7nnig1m0e.apps.googleusercontent.com"),
```

i've making sure that its installed :

```
flutter pub add google_sign_in
```

Does it deprecated?

If there is any better guide for applying google sign in please let me know :D
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi did you try the answer.

Comment: i was so desperate that time, and im leaving all of my code the chatgpt and somehow it works. funnily i forgot the structure so i dont know which one has changed that made my code works :(

Comment: I reported this issue here: https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/9868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explored the **pub.dev** Flutter libraries and adhered to the installation instructions for *firebase_ui_oauth_google*. Running the command below should automatically add the necessary dependencies:

```
flutter pub add firebase_ui_oauth_google
```

This command will ensure that the correct dependencies are added, ultimately solving the problem.